# PC monitor flickering after power comes back

Tags: desktop

Suppose I am working on my computer, suddenly power supply get cut and after 1 blink my PC continues(in the same screen I was working) through the UPS , after 1 minute power comes back and my pc goes full flickering mode, nothing is visible except flickering dots and no function is working, then I have to directly power off the UPS to shut down my system and for this sometimes after powering on my UPS again, PC goes recovery mode. Why is this happening??

(My pc is younger than 1 year, and UPS is from APC company.)

Please give solution...

Comment: Sounds like a hardware problem. The UPS is the immediate suspect, but the only way to verify this is to replace it, which you might be able to demand if it's still under warranty.

Comment: Could also be the powersupply not able to take the powerspike, but its also possible the UPS can't take the load of the pc.

Answer (score 1):

There are [different types of uninterruptible power supplies (UPS)](https://www.vertiv.com/en-emea/about/news-and-insights/articles/educational-articles/what-are-the-different-types-of-ups-systems/):

- *Standby*: The UPS inverter is not running, and output power is derived from the mains, *until* there is sufficient drop in mains power to trigger the inverter to start, which can take a cycle or so (e.g., 20 ms for 50 Hz mains).
- *Line Interactive*: These supplies are quicker to react, taking just 5 ms or so to readjust when the mains power fluctuates.
- *Continuously Online (Double Conversion)*: The mains charges the battery, but *all* output to devices comes from a continually running inverter using that battery. This type is least efficient, but most effective at eliminating power loss and voltage surges.

Here are three likely causes of your issue:

- The PC might be unable to handle the brief gap in power while a *standby* (most common for home use, and most efficient) UPS starts. You *might* need a continuously online UPS for your particular setup.
- The connected devices might draw more power than the UPS can handle. As the lead-acid battery in a UPS ages, it is able to supply less power. Use the test button on the UPS to check if there is sufficient power. Batteries can be replaced, if needed and if economically feasible.
- If some devices connected to the PC were not plugged into the UPS, there could have been a ground-loop voltage across the ports, causing the PC to behave erratically or causing permanent damage. Yes, the UPS would run longer if powering *only* the PC, but that could be the cause of the issue, as well.